# iOS certificates in different folder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

Is it in anyway possible to have Xcode reference provisioning profiles in a different folder?

We're looking at being able to change certificates/profiles on the fly.  We work with multiple companies who use the same code.  We're thinking of having a sub folder per company to store the iOS side of things in.  The only things that change are the template, the certificates and the icons.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about where the provisioning live. If you let xCode download them you can have them synced easily. The most annoying part is not the certificates but the certificates and the associated private/public keys. What I do myself is create different keychain files for each company I work with, so that I can more easily manage them and share them if I need to.

File->New Keychain in the keychain access, then drag over the appropiate items to this new keychain.